# how to use an @Output() property inline without use a function into the controller

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular2-template

is it possible to use the `countRitiri` output property inside its parent `<mat-tab>` without to call  a function in the current component `updateCountRitiri` that updates the variable `countRitiri` that consequently  is used in the  `<mat-tab>` template

this is my actual situation:

```
<mat-tab [label]="'Total count: (' + countRitiri + ')'" >
          <ant-ritiri-compact (countRitiri)="updateCountRitiri($event)"></ant-ritiri-compact>
</mat-tab>
```

and in the component

```
updateCountRitiri(value)
  {
    this.countRitiri = value;
    
  }
```

maybe using a template variable... or some similar trick

i'd like to do something similar

```
//pseudocode

<mat-tab #mytabvariable [label]="'Total count: (' + countRitiri + ')'" >
          <ant-ritiri-compact (countRitiri)="($event) => { #mytabvariable.label = $event }"></ant-ritiri-compact>
</mat-tab>
```

Comment: While it's doable, logic shoul be moved out of the template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `countRitiri` is not declared `private` or `protected`, then yes you can use it directly inside its component's template like so

```
<mat-tab [hidden]="countRitiri == 0" [label]="'Total count: (' + countRitiri + ')'" >
          <ant-ritiri-compact (countRitiri)="countRitiri = $event"></ant-ritiri-compact>
</mat-tab>
```

Comment: It's exactly what i need! Thanks